# What is a proper Pythonic way to write an asynchronous generator?

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, yield

The **Reader.read()** needs to infinitely listen to **Api.listen()** which in its turn infinitely listens to an opened web-socket.
What would be a proper way to code down the following?

```
class Api:
    async def listen(self):
        async with websockets.connect(URL) as sock:
            while True:
                yield await sock.recv()

class Reader:
    async def read(self):
        api = Api()
        while True:
            data = await api.listen()
            ...

reader = Reader()
reader.read()
```

No surprise, this code produces an error:

```
TypeError: object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Should I implement something like `Api.Listen.__await__()`?

How to code such an *async read-yield* pattern properly?

Comment: Did you check this? https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/

Comment: Yes, I did. Still, not sure what would be a right way to implement this simple async pattern.